# Segmentation fault trying to run bitcoind on raspberry-pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, bitcoin, bitcoind

I installed a bitcoin node using a raspberry-pi 2 + usb stick of 128 Giga (hosting the blockchain). But cannot make it run. This is what i get:

```
$ bitcoind
  Segmentation fault
```

After googling a while, the possible causes I found are:

1. Corrupted SD card or program
2. Electric supply issue (lack of voltage)

Hopefully it's non of them. Any insight or advice?

Comment: Lack of information. You may try [raspberry stack exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what client and version are you using?